# AD7705 - Problems with setup and communication with Raspberry Pi via bitbanged SPI in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, spi, adc

I am new here and desperately searching for a solution to my problem. I am currently trying to make my Raspberry Pi communicate to an AD7705 16bit-ADC with Python. Unfortunately though, things aren't going as expected...
The circuit looks like this: [AD7705 Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHiQR.png)

I did a lot of research and studied the datasheet carefully to select the parts to meet all of the AD7705's requirements. Everything is soldered to a stripboard.
To keep my PCB as simple as possible I cannot use hardware SPI so I am bound to bitbanging. Since CS is tied to GND, communication is reduced to MOSI, MISO and CLK. I suppose that I've done a mistake in implementing SPI for the AD7705. I've worked with an MPC3008 before using bitbanged SPI and got it to work properly so I suppose that I have a huge logical thinking error in my implementation for the AD7705.

At the moment, My routine looks like this:

```
send 0010 0000 -> request write access to clock register
send 0000 0100 -> configure clock register for 2.4576MHz operation
send 0001 0000 -> request write access to setup register
send 0100 0010 -> set gain = 1, buffered mode and perform self-calibration
send 0000 1000 -> request read access to communiation register
read 1 byte
```

This is quite similar to the "Flowchart for Setting Up and Reading from the AD7705" from the datasheet, with small differences in the written data to the clock register (I am using a resonator with another frequency).

The problem is that I only receive kind of random and not reproducible bytes. And I am not even trying to read actual data yet. Can you spot any mistake?

I tried to provide all information on my method, though I cannot explain the whole datasheet. The problem should not be hardware-sided, though.

```
def send(sendcmd):
    for i in range(8):
        GPIO.output(CLK, 0)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        if (sendcmd & 0x80):
            GPIO.output(MOSI, 1)
        else:
            GPIO.output(MOSI, 0)
        GPIO.output(CLK, 1)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        sendcmd <<= 1

def read():
    readbyte=0
    for i in range(8):
        GPIO.output(CLK, 0)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        GPIO.output(CLK, 1)
        time.sleep(0.0001)
        readbit = GPIO.input(MISO)
        readbyte |= readbit
        readbyte <<= 1
    return readbyte >> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed a digital oscilloscope (great instruments!) from a friend and figured out that the CLK signal was switching too fast, so I increased the waiting time between CLK HI/LO switches to 0.001s.
Afterwards, I found out that I didn't receive any proper signal from the ADC's DOUT pin, even though my bytes where sent properly, so I replaced the chip.

Now everything works as expected, so my advice for everyone: remember to generously respect timing criteria when bitbanging SPI! =)

Answer (score 1):

"send 0000 0100 -> configure clock register for 2.4576MHz operation"
rather send 0000 1100 (devide by 2 bit) with 4.9152MHz

Comment: What do you mean by "rather send"

Comment: rath·er
adverb
used to indicate one's preference in a particular matter. Rather send b00001100 than "replacing the chip"